# How do I save my game in LittleBigPlanet 2 on PS3?

Tags: little-big-planet-2

I keep looking up how to save, and I cannot find a way to save my game.

How do I save my LittleBigPlanet 2 game on PS3?

Answer (score 7):

The game automatically saves for you. If you are playing online, you will see a little spinning planet at the bottom left of the screen when it is saving, and if you are playing offline you will see a little running Sackboy image in the bottom left of the screen.

In general, if you have returned to your pod before quitting the game, you can safely assume it has saved. It does not save your progress mid-level, though - you will have to start levels over from the beginning when you play again. It does remember what stickers or objects you found, though.

However, if you are making new levels of your own in the level creator, you will have to tell the game to save in one of two ways:

> Start > Switch to Play Mode > Save Changes

or:

> Start > Save/Save As

Answer (score 2):

Much like little big planet 1, your character actually saves automatically after each level. And each time you log out from your pod or whatever. Just look for the little logo down in the bottom right corner to see when it is saving.

Answer (score 0):

To save your level (created by selecting a slot on "Your Moon") you press Start and select "Save Changes"

Or, you could "Switch to Play Mode" which will bring up a prompt asking you if you want to save your level.